Azure ML Prompt Flow Creation and Cloning Failed
Creating or cloning prompt flow both result in the following error - "This request is not authorized to perform this operation". However, I have both the "contributor" and "Data Sceintist" role for this AML. Besides, creating runtime is also not possible as the button for creating is grayed out. I'm not sure whether these two problems are related.
Has anyone encountered the same issue?
AML Screenshot 1 (https://i.sstatic.net/zOehilI5.png)
AML Screenshot 2 (https://i.sstatic.net/fzShpSh6.png)
I could not find any useful documentation on this issue. All the tutorials i have watched also dont have the same issue..
